# Unable to add twitter SDK 3.3.0 to Android Studio 3.1 project

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter, sdk, integration

[image]I've already updated Android Studio to latest version 3.1.3. Need to add twitter sharing in app now. But when I add twitter SDK dependencies, I get a bunch of errors.

Here are the twitter dependencies I'm trying to add:

```
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.3.0'
```

I've tried adding this one as well:

```
implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.3.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Please help me resolve dependency issues with this or if it can be resolved by using some older twitter SDK version.

Comment: There are few errors which you should check and set **min API** to 26 first, then check the `ChatHelper.java` file to see and solve an issue if there is any then tell me what changes..Also, Check if you have enabled proguard, this might be an another issue too.

Comment: Also, it seems like the another issue is Android Dex limit which you might want to check : https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/wiki/Getting-Started#add-twitter-kit-dependencies

Comment: @Mohsen Proguard is already enabled:


buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: Nothing helped to resolved this issue yet. @Mohsen

Comment: It's not enabled since the parameter after 'minifyEnabled' is **"false"** which let it be false. Anyways, did you check with setting the min API to 26 and reinvalidate caches?